# Define a random variable from response match in karate

Tags: karate

How can I define a variable as a random match?

```
item[]
0{}
1{
_id:item
}
2{}
3{}
```

I want to define a match not with `item[1]._id` but with `item[random]._id`.

Could you please help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

Just a warning that trying to add such dynamic behavior to your tests makes them less maintainable in the long term.

Here is an [example](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-junit4/src/test/java/com/intuit/karate/junit4/demos/random-jsonpath.feature) that works:

```
* def size = response.items.length
* def index = Math.floor(Math.random() * size)
* def item = response.items[index]
```

Comment: `* match $.data.subjectById.itemsForSubjectCoordinator[0].docReferenceId == #present'

`* def topItem0 = $.data.subjectById.itemsForSubjectCoordinator[0].docReferenceId`

Comment: @Thanoon your question is incomplete, may be it is `response.item` for you - so it is time for me to refer you to this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: this code is going just to select my topitemid in my test
i have define my test as well but i need to select another topitemid with a really name that i want it works like random with if loop maybe!
i want it to go into my list and look if its the save work in the list then take the itemid
@peter

Comment: i do not want to use this match again for list 1 like ->
`* match $.data.subjectById.itemsForSubjectCoordinator[1].docReferenceId == #present'` to get the match 
i want it like a random where ever it is it has to be selected

Comment: @Thanoon look at other questions on stack overflow and see if you can figure out what you can do better